# how to use clickable image button inside div and call a js script function once image is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i added a click-able image button near an image thumbnail but for some reason the image is not click able and it doesn't pass any value to function it calls(postLike function). Here i got and example in js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ymdPa/

could any one look at it and tell me why my clickable image button is not firing ?

part of the code that has the clickable button :

```
<div id='like"+pageurl+"' style='float: right; padding: 5px 2px 2px;'> <img class='liker' onclick=postLike("+imageurl+","+username+","+albumPicurl+","+userid+","+pageurl+","+time+","+text+") src='"+likeimage+"' border='0'></div>
```

edited:
once the user click the button i want to change the button image and the function it calls to something different like below but it doesn't work!(code below doesn't**strong text** replace the image button )

```
$('like+e+').html(" <img class='lb-liked' onclick='deleteLikeLB(&quot;" + a + "&quot;,&quot;" + b + "&quot;,&quot;" + c + "&quot;,&quot;" + d + "&quot;,&quot;" + e + "&quot;,&quot;" + f + "&quot;,&quot;" + g + "&quot;)' src='http://www.peppertt.com/wp-2013/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Facebook-like-not.jpg' title='like' border='0' />");
```

code:

```
function postLike(a, b, c, d, e, f, g) {
  alert("Hello World!");
  alert("imageURL:" + a + "\nuserName:" + b + "\nalbumPicurl:" + c + "\nuserId:" + d + "\nPageURL:" + e + "\nTime:" + f + "\nText:" + g);
  $('like+e+').html(" <img class='lb-liked' onclick='deleteLikeLB(&quot;" + a + "&quot;,&quot;" + b + "&quot;,&quot;" + c + "&quot;,&quot;" + d + "&quot;,&quot;" + e + "&quot;,&quot;" + f + "&quot;,&quot;" + g + "&quot;)' src='./liked.png' title='like' border='0' />");
}
var imageurl = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Panda_Cub_from_Wolong,_Sichuan,_China.JPG";
var username = "tim";
var albumPicurl = "http://somesite.com/albumpic.jpg";
var userid = "3453454545";
var pageurl = "http://somesite.com/page2.html";
var time = "34534545435";
var text = "lifeiscool";
var fullname = "smith";
var likeimage = "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTyTZ5jtJ3VxrorGg0ywxXfEstaZWce2he-_6LSgFwsnch6xYUm";
$(".content").append("<div id='grid-cell' style='padding:5px'><a style='text-decoration:none' href='./dl.php?name=brian&imageurl=" + imageurl + "'><img class='photo-grid' src='" + imageurl + "' width=200 height=200 title='" + username + "' /></a><div id='like" + pageurl + "' style='float: right; padding: 5px 2px 2px;'> <img class='liker' onclick=postLike(" + imageurl + "," + username + "," + albumPicurl + "," + userid + "," + pageurl + "," + time + "," + text + ") src='" + likeimage + "' border='0'></div><div class='moreInfo2'><a style='color:#000;text-decoration:none' href='/" + username + "' target='_blank'>" + userid + "(" + fullname + ")</a></div></div>");


<div class="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's really a horribly formatted bunch of code. If you formatted it with better use of white space (including line breaks) and/or did some basic browser console (`console.log()`) debugging it would be more obvious that you're creating an inline `onclick=` attribute that has unquoted string values in it.

Your code produces this string:

```
<img class="liker" onclick="postLike(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Panda_Cub_from_Wolong,_S…umpic.jpg,3453454545,http://somesite.com/page2.html,34534545435,lifeiscool)"
```

...but what you need it to do is produce this string:

```
<img class='liker' onclick='postLike("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Panda_Cub_from_Wolong,_Sichuan,_China.JPG","tim","http://somesite.com/albumpic.jpg","3453454545","http://somesite.com/page2.html","34534545435","lifeiscool")'
```

Note the quotation marks around the string values that are the function parameters? You need to adjust your code so that it produces these quotation marks, perhaps like this:

```
"onclick='postLike(\"" +imageurl+"\",\""+username+"\",\""+albumPicurl+"\",\""
+userid+"\",\""+pageurl+"\",\""+time+"\",\""+text+"\")'"
```

Even if you fix that, your fiddle won't work because your `postLike()` function declaration is inside the default `onload` wrapper (as specified in the panel on the left), and inline `onEvent=` attributes can only call global functions.

Working version: http://jsfiddle.net/ymdPa/6/

Since you're using jQuery, why don't you get rid of the inline `onclick=` and create the handlers with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, what an unreadable mess. No wonder there are syntax errors in there. For example you're not passing strings to the postLike() function. And probably a bunch of other errors which I can't be bothered finding.

```
<img class="liker" onclick="postLike(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Panda_Cub_from_Wolong,_Sichuan,_China.JPG,tim,http://somesite.com/albumpic.jpg,3453454545,http://somesite.com/page2.html,34534545435,lifeiscool)" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTyTZ5jtJ3VxrorGg0ywxXfEstaZWce2he-_6LSgFwsnch6xYUm" border="0">
```

Comment: did you see the demo in jsfiddle site ?i am passing variables to postLink function.Problem is that function call is not correct ! the clickable button on its own outside append work but when i added to append then stops working!! hope some one tell me what part of function call is incorrect !